# How can I make the html output from button_to have single quotes instead of double?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got this line:

```
<%= button_to 'Post', newpost_path(:type => 'short_note') %>
```

which outputs this:

```
<form method="post" action="/posts/newpost?type=short_note" class="button-to"><div><input type="submit" value="Add" /></div></form>;
```

But I need the output to have single quotes, not double. How can I do this?

```
<form method='post' action='/posts/newpost?type=short_note' class='button-to'><div><input type='submit' value='Add' /></div></form>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= (button_to 'Post', newpost_path(:type => 'short_note')).gsub('"', '\'') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

create a file in **rails_root/lib** called **url_helper_overrides.rb** that simply overrides the button to method.  Or you could add the button_to method below to your application_helper.  This method is taken straight from the [UrlHelper source in Rails (Github Link)](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.1/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L306), I simply replaced the double quotes with single quotes.

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module UrlHelper

      def button_to(name, options = {}, html_options = {}) 
        html_options = html_options.stringify_keys
        convert_boolean_attributes!(html_options, %w( disabled ))

        method_tag = ''
        if (method = html_options.delete('method')) && %w{put delete}.include?(method.to_s)
          method_tag = tag('input', :type => 'hidden', :name => '_method', :value => method.to_s)
        end 

        form_method = method.to_s == 'get' ? 'get' : 'post'

        remote = html_options.delete('remote')

        request_token_tag = ''
        if form_method == 'post' && protect_against_forgery?
          request_token_tag = tag(:input, :type => "hidden", :name => request_forgery_protection_token.to_s, :value => form_authenticity_token)
        end 

        url = options.is_a?(String) ? options : self.url_for(options)
        name ||= url 

        html_options = convert_options_to_data_attributes(options, html_options)

        html_options.merge!("type" => "submit", "value" => name)

        ("<form method='#{form_method}' action='#{html_escape(url)}' #{"data-remote='true'" if remote} class='button_to'><div>" +
          method_tag + tag("input", html_options) + request_token_tag + "</div></form>").html_safe
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to `gsub(/"/, "'")` but this is really ugly